# block direct access to file but allow access through jquerys load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I'm using **jQuery** to display a certain page to a user through it's `.load()` function. I am doing this to allow user customization to the website, allowing them to fit it to their needs.

At the moment, I am trying to display the file `feed.php` inside of a container within `main.php`;

I have come across a problem where I would like to prevent direct access to the file **(i.e: going directly to the path of it (***./feed.php***))**, but still allowing it to be served through the `.load()` function.

If I use the `.htaccess` `deny from all` method for this, I get a 403 on that specific part of the page. I can't find any other solution to this problem; disallowing me to achieve what I want.

This is my current **(simplified)** `script` and `html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dock-left-container").load("feed.php"); // load feed.php into the dock-left-container div
</script>

<div class="dock-leftside" id="dock-left-container"></div> // dock-left-container div
```

If anyone could suggest a solution through **.htaccess**, **php**, or even a **completely different** way to do this, I'd be very grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using load(), function. Are you checking any condition before it ? It seems to be an authentication system implementation..

Comment: @LukeP.Issac no it is not.. it's for layout customisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps to achieve:

1. In the `.load` function of jquery post a security code.
2. In the Feed.php page place a PHP condition if the posted `security_code` params found and match with `security_code` passed in the `.load` then only allow to access the page otherwise restrict.

Please follow below changes in your existing code to achieve it.

**JS**

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['security_code'] = randomCode();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dock-left-container").load("feed.php", {
       security_code: '<?= $_SESSION['security_code']; ?>'
   }); // load feed.php into the dock-left-container div
</script>
```

**PHP**

> Place php condition in the top of feed.php

```
if(isset($_POST['security_code']) && $_POST['security_code'] == $_SESSION['security_code']){
    //Feed.php page's all the stuff will go here
}else{
    echo "No direct access of this page will be allowed.";
}
```

Comment: why `89764123`? would it be a better idea to randomly generate a security code through PHP? thanks

Comment: If you generate a random number then you have to store then number in PHP session and then pass it in the .load and in the php page you have to match the posted value with session value.

Comment: I know :) I was just curious if that code was necessary haha

Comment: Does your JS code is in the PHP file? If yes then which I told in the previous comment easily can be implemented.

Comment: No it is not necessary but if we implement then somehow we can increase the security little bit more.

Comment: @RahutPatel fair enough.

Comment: Adding the `security_code` adds nothing extra since it's easily accessible by simply viewing the `.js` source. Just as [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40190301/215042) it's just simply a false sense of security. If your browser can access the file via JS it's just a simple matter of opening it's 'network tab' in the debugger and looking at the actual request. This can then be easily 'mirrored'.

Answer (score 2):

`feed.php`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    readfile('myfeed.xml');
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}
```

jQuery sends a `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header by default. This is not, by far, anything remotely secure since HTTP headers are easily sent/spoofed. But it will stop the occasional user trying to access the feed directly.

You can, additionaly, check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` header (but, again, this is easily spoofed) and, ofcourse, use your normal session logic to make sure the user is logged on if that's a requirement to access the feed.

Either way: there's no way to make this 'water tight'. If your browser can (should be able to) access the feed in some way then it's simply a matter of opening the debugger, having a look at the actual request sent in the network tab and sending the exact same headers/request to get to the file from, say, Curl. Actually, you will see the response of the request (i.e. the actual feed) in the debugger as well.

Repeat after me: if my (or a user's) browser can access the feed 'from jQuery' (via an AJAX request or whatever) then the feed is accessible to that user if he's even just a little bit more persistent than giving up immediately. Only using a session will keep out 'unauthorized' users because it relies on being logged in. After having logged in the request is visible no matter what and that request can be 'forged' to be sent from any other application no matter what.

Comment: may you post a reason as to why this might work & or how to alter it? thanks

Comment: It should work because load function internally does and xmlhttprequest which is not the case when you are hitting the url directly. And here, the condition is checking for http headers for xmlhttprequest.