# How to prevent load file multiple times in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, load

Might my subject of this thread is same of multiple threads on stackoverflow but please believe me I have been read all the threads on this platform and and over the google but yet I not get the expected answer of my question below- 
When I clicking the button first time the modal div load the URL properly but after closing the modal div and hit the button to open again it load twice. means at every button click the modal load URL twice of previous load URL. Suppose if this time LOAD URL load 2 time next time its load 4 times and so on..

Even, I used `return false` but I don't the get the answer , I also read the answer of other thread but it not matching to my question codes.

Note: Please I am rules of stackoverflow policy and not making this thread after read all thread and not get answer then, Please not mark this Duplicate / Under Pending and any negative marks.
 Where I am doing wrong in my code I am new in this Debug.

```js
$('#reveal_AddSenderMod').on('click', function() {
  $('.modal.fade.modal-style2').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').find('#loadURL').load('./loadPage.html').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />

<button type="button" id="reveal_AddSenderMod" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-style2" style="width:75px; display: block;margin: 0 auto;" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">OPEN MODEL</button>

<div class="modal fade modal-style2 hidden-print" id="modal-style2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="loadURL" class="animated fadeIn"></div>
          <button data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE MODEL</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).on("click", "button[data-dismiss='modal']", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('div.modal-body').find('div#loadURL').find('div.senderIDAdd_module').empty(); //remove() is also not works
 });
 </script>
<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="http://shashani-humanth.github.io/Notebook-AdminPanel/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding event muilple time.

On click, you should just open modal. not bind. Bind should be done one time.

```
$('#reveal_AddSenderMod').on('click', function() {
  $('.modal.fade.modal-style2').modal('show');
})

$('.modal.fade.modal-style2').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').find('#loadURL').load('./loadPage.html').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });
```

**//Some dummy code**

```
$('body').on('click', '#on-submit-senderid', function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem("review_submitte")) {
          return;
        }
        if(!$('input[name="sender_id_confirm"]').is(':checked')) {
            mkNoti(['Ops!'],['Please agree the condition to get Custom Sender ID'],{ sound: true, status:['danger'],dismissable: false });
            return;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                            ...
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.status == 'success') {
                        //SUCCESS
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        mkNoti([response.title],[response.message],{ sound: true, status:[response.status],dismissable: false });
                        return false;
                    }
                    localStorage.setItem("review_submitte", "true")
                }
            });
            hide_loader();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but why inside the `loadPage.html` jQuery code works twice `https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/rcpwzfav/2/` with this code I am seeing `mkNoti` notification multiple times. Sir WHY ? PLS Help

Comment: .load('./loadPage.html') load everything again.. try using local storage, to mark that loaded. else dont call load everytime

Comment: Nope sir it not worked, I have been update the JSFIDDLE with my original code `https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/rcpwzfav/6/` error image `https://ibb.co/RTCp7Dx`

Comment: why u are loading html ?? why not just call method and do work in main page

Comment: because the content and things is must show in model. it looks will bad when I call to main page

Comment: I have not really any experience with sandbox yet. as I have learned I mentioned in JS Fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/rcpwzfav/6/`

Comment: SIR, could you help me? I try to solve this from many days but it happens by me. It would be your great help sir. Pls help pls pls pls

Comment: Sir , I am not able to run this code, It is show multiple time and twice. This code is not working as here is my JS Fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/n3egd01m/1/. Please help me.

Comment: what PHP line is doing there :(

Comment: I use PHP to prevent direct access to loaded file via jQuery and at PHP loaded page first I check the session passed by from this jQuery and then access other contains. [referrerLink] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190185/block-direct-access-to-file-but-allow-access-through-jquerys-load-function)

Comment: sir is this possible to solve this issue , in this lockdown I per-day try to fix this you are my last hope.

Comment: half knowledge is very dangerous I am still awaiting for your answer

Comment: hi, sorry i didnt see message. can u ping me in chat

Comment: In which chat you are taking about ? Whatsapp ? / facebook ?

Comment: I am awaiting for your reply sir. pls help

Comment: @ShubhamSingh Hi, lets have chat: https://www.facebook.com/deepak.dipu